# How to fix "Error: Please select a valid Python interpreter" in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

**Error**:

> Error: Please select a valid Python interpreter

**Screenshot**:

[image]

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Your Pycharm has a hard time determining the path to the installed Python interpreter. Normally it automatically can, but if not, here are the steps:

- Expand the environment
- Then you will be asked for the path where Python is installed
- Navigate to the directory where Python is installed and select the Python executable

This section from the Pycharm docs will help you:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html

Comment: It's asking for enterpreneur options

Comment: python executable refering the same as python interpretor

Comment: Error running 'sql4': Cannot find SDK for Run configuration sql4

Comment: 'scratch': @NotNull method com/intellij/execution/configurations/GeneralCommandLine.getExePath must not return null

Answer (score 1):

Go to run->Edit configurations
then select Python interpreter location of the python installed (`python.exe`)
then after change apply the changes.

[image: attached image].

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I had changed the name of my module, but the old name still persisted here and there. I fixed it in the Python plugin for IntelliJ IDEA -- deleting the old module and recreating it from sources -- and then it worked in PyCharm. It might have been possible to fix it in PyCharm, I was just switching IDEs out of frustration.