# Error with Pycharm: "Failed to create a virtual environment"

Tags: python, pycharm

How can I solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

I already tried

```
pip install virtuale
```

I'm just trying to code on pycharm.

Comment: See the configuration fo "**Python interpreter**" and you have it set to "**<No interpreter>**"? That's what the error is talking about. You need to set it to the path to the Python you installed, or select one from the dropdown if there is one. This is _even before_ worrying about the error on virtual environments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "Error: Please select a valid Python interpreter" in Pycharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49792127/how-to-fix-error-please-select-a-valid-python-interpreter-in-pycharm)